# Install GDAL Python [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, geolocation, geo

My version of Python is  [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 but I cannot see a release 1916 in http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php. Can I use an older release with my version of Python?

I am trying to learn more Django skills and wanted to add some mapping functionality to my site http://rossdjangoawesomeapp2.herokuapp.com/. The site is purely for testing / experimental purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to grab pre-compiled libraries from here when I had to develop on Windows:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/